# I have used the z index -1 because the links were not appearing on the image background. now my input box is disabled along submit button

Tags: html, css

I have used the z index -1 because the links were not appearing on the image background. now my input box is disabled along submit button.

```
contact {
      position: relative;
      min-height: 100vh;
      padding: 50px 100px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7)url(3571952.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      background-blend-mode: darken;
      z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: Please include enough HTML for us to see your structure, as it stands we have no idea where your input elements and so on are in relation to the element you have placed at z-index -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a negative z-index, the div is placed under body and when you check in console the body tag will be highlighted instead of input. Try to remove z-index from contact class and add position absolute to the links and add z-index with higher value.

```
contact {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7)url(3571952.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
  z-index: 0;
}

links {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```